# Rails API using Github OAuth authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'd like to build an app with a server-side Rails 5 API serving JSON data, and a React or other JS front-end, but I would like users to authenticate with their github accounts.

So when the app starts the user would log in with github and then receive a JWT token to use to interact with the Rails API.

Where are some resources I could use to get started here?

Comment: Currently looking at the devise gem here: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/1020

If this works, I'll update and answer my own question.

Comment: Did you find any good resource for this? I'm starting exactly the same way you did. So, I'd really appreciate anything you found around this topic to get started!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rolling my own using Faraday and manual api calls.

https://github.com/Ada-Developers-Academy/ada-prs-api/tree/authentication

Currently it's on hold as I'm switching to a React-Firebase framework as it's better supported and seems more scalable.